# Custom RelativeLayout with two view in animation

Tags: android, android-layout, animation

I couldn't find anywhere about this situation. 
I have two views in a RelativeLayout.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
android:background="@color/transparent">
<View
    android:id="@+id/view_mask1"
    android:layout_width="50dp"
    android:layout_height="50dp"
    android:background="@drawable/tutrial_icon_bg_circle"
    android:layout_centerInParent="true"
    android:visibility="visible"/>
<View
    android:id="@+id/view_mask"
    android:layout_width="30dp"
    android:layout_height="30dp"
    android:background="@drawable/tutorial_icon_bg"
    android:layout_centerInParent="true"
    android:visibility="visible"/>
 </RelativeLayout>
```

Also I have two different animation on this views. When I set animations in an activity, animations are working good. 
It is time for problem, I wanna use this views where I want. Because I don't want to set all animations again and again for all times. I wanna use in an adapter like this;

```
View v = inflater.inflate(R.layout.animation_layout, null);
LinearLayout ll =(LinearLayout) findViewById(R.id.layout);
ll.addView(v);
```

So, I think I have to create a customView but how?

Answer (score 0):

Nobody has answered but I have found a solution on my own. 
I have created a class that extends View.

```
public class TutorialIcon extends View {

View maskView, maskView1, v;
public TutorialIcon(Context context) {
    super(context);
    v = LayoutInflater.from(context).inflate(R.layout.tutorial_icon, null);
    this.maskView = v.findViewById(R.id.view_mask);
    this.maskView1 = v.findViewById(R.id.view_mask1);
}

public View view(){
    createRecursiveAnimations();
    return v;
}
private void createRecursiveAnimations1() {
//animation1
}
private void createRecursiveAnimations2() {
//animation2
}
}
```

tutorial_icon.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
android:background="@color/transparent">
<View
    android:id="@+id/view_mask1"
    android:layout_width="50dp"
    android:layout_height="50dp"
    android:background="@drawable/tutrial_icon_bg_circle"
    android:layout_centerInParent="true"
    android:visibility="visible" />
<View
    android:id="@+id/view_mask"
    android:layout_width="30dp"
    android:layout_height="30dp"
    android:background="@drawable/tutorial_icon_bg"
    android:layout_centerInParent="true"
    android:visibility="visible"/>
</RelativeLayout>
```

And finally, I have added my animation view in to my list view adapter.

Adapter.java

```
@Override
public View getView(final int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {
convertView = null;
if (convertView == null) {
        convertView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.cell_catalog_tags, null);
        Relativelayout layout = (RelativeLayout) convertView.findViewById(R.id.layout);
            TutorialIcon t = new TutorialIcon(context);
            layout.addView(t.view());
    }
}
```

Hope this helps someone.